# Delete record and all associated records, even if there are no associated records

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this app, where users create expense reports. Each report has many receipts, and I need to be able to let users delete their reports with the associated receipts. I have a sql statement now that does just that but it only works IF there the report has receipts, so if it has no receipts the report doesnt get deleted:

```
    mysql_query("DELETE expense_general, expense_receipts FROM expense_general JOIN expense_receipts ON expense_general.id = expense_receipts.expense_general_id WHERE expense_general.id = {$expenseID}");
```

$expenseID is the report record ID number. so I do I get the statement to delete the reports with no receipts?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Perhaps a trigger would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` query, i.e.

```
DELETE expense_general, expense_receipts 
FROM expense_general 
LEFT JOIN expense_receipts ON expense_general.id = expense_receipts.expense_general_id 
WHERE expense_general.id = {$expenseID}
```

this will match on the `expense_general` table, regardless of whether there is anything linked in the `expense_receipts` table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a "foreign key relationship" defined between your tables.  The detail table `expense_receipts` will have a foreign key relationship with `expense_general`, and when you delete rows from `expense_general`, the corresponding detail rows are also deleted.

Googling for "mysql foreign key" should give you many tutorials to choose from.